# Applications launched as administrator takes long to load/show

Tags: windows-10, administrator

When ever I launch an application that requires administrator access it takes very long (15-30 Seconds).

I have tried many things when you search for my issue on the internet, none has worked so far that I tried.

But the following scenario makes me believe the issue is with my user profile.

I created a new test user on my pc with administrator access and it launches any application that requires administrator access fast.

So I could fix my own issue by creating a new user for my self to login, but I would like to figure out what causes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard fix for a broken Windows User Profile is to back up the documents, email, favorites and all else.  Delete the broken profile, restart, re-create the profile and recover the documents.

You can decide to change the use name and make a new profile and move the documents over.

Repairing the broken profile is generally not practical in any normal way. Like finding a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Marking as the answer, cause that is what I was planning to-do anyway if I could not find the issue. Thank you John